# Ubuntu on Macbook

Tags: macbook

I have never used Ubuntu before but I want to get to know it since I am studying computer science in college. I have two MacBooks and one of them I take with me everywhere and another I keep at home. I have the 2015 12' MacBook and when I tried to install Ubuntu on it, the keyboard and mouse were not working. I am sure many of you are aware of this issue. So far it seems that nobody has found a fix unfortunately, however I am curious if anyone has found a work around it. Also, my other laptop is a MacBook Pro 15', is it worth taking this with me to use Ubuntu? I use the other laptop because of how small it is, but I don't know if Ubuntu is worth it enough that I take my other laptop with me to use it. Thanks everyone. Any tips and help is appreciated cause this is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu, it doesn't matter what laptop you use, it will work. Now, of course, there are some issues like the one you raised about the mouse and keyboard not working. This could be easily solved if you just use Virtualbox on your Mac to run Ubuntu, unless you want to dual boot(and need the hardware to run programs that need a lot of RAM for example).

As for which Mac to take around with you, that's up to you. Install Ubuntu on both, on one, and take whichever you want with you.